# Error while installing Atom in Kali Linux

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, atom-editor, kali-linux

I was trying to install Atom in Kali Linux Live.
And after command

```
dpkg -i ~/Downloads/atom-amd64.deb
```

I get error

```
dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/root/Downloads/atom-amd64.deb': No such file or directory
```

I have tried as both root and non-root users

I am using Kali Linux Live with Persistence (Bootable USB)

Same kind of thing happens with Visual Studio code too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may have to install kali Linux on the device as Kali Linux Live provides the tools for hacking. If you want to install software, then you have to install Kali or manually install it without a package.

Check out this Reddit post about the issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4zgrzs/is_it_possible_to_install_software_on_kali_linux/